# Error in a ns-3 simulation?

Tags: c++, ns-3, ndnsim

I am trying to run a simulation but I keep getting some kind of error. I am not an expert on C++, but I think it's due to header file include. I am getting the following error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 void OutInterest(Ptr<const ns3::ndn::InterestHeader> interestHeader,Ptr<const ns3::ndn::Face> face) {
                            ^
../scratch/vndn_simulation.cc:87:52: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 void OutInterest(Ptr<const ns3::ndn::InterestHeader> interestHeader,Ptr<const ns3::ndn::Face> face) {
                                                    ^
../scratch/vndn_simulation.cc:87:28: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 void OutInterest(Ptr<const ns3::ndn::InterestHeader> interestHeader,Ptr<const ns3::ndn::Face> face) {
```

Any idea on how to solve this error?

Comment: You cannot post images, and there's a reason for it! You should not abuse  screen shots of your error messages here, but put the verbatim error text into your post.

Comment: Are the errors during compilation?  linking? or run-time?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews   
During compilation

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Any ideas,i will appreciate it and thanks

Comment: We could help you more if you add the **text** of the compiler error message to your post and also indicate where in the file the error corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

It says here:

> ```
> class NameComponents;
>        ^
> In file included from ./ns3/ndn-v2v-net-device-face.h:31:0,
>                  from ../scratch/vndn_simulation.cc:15:
> ./ns3/ndn-header-helper.h:34:21: note: ‘ns3::ndn::NameComponents’ has a previous declaration here
>         typedef Name NameComponents;
>                      ^
> ```

that you cannot forward declare `NameComponents` because the compiler has already seen that it is a `typedef` and not a class.